# 1 Delete query from 2 select queries

Tags: mysql

I understand the title could be a bit vague, so I'll try to explain what I would like to do with a little example.

I have a table called students . I would like to delete all records from students that are multiple times in my table. So all records of Peter & Aaron have to be deleted.

```
SELECT student, count(student) AS cnt FROM `testtable` GROUP BY `student` HAVING cnt > 1
```

I also would like to delete all records where mathematics is 8.

```
SELECT id FROM `testtable` WHERE mathematics = 8
```

But how do i come from these select querys to a delete query? And is it even possible to combine the 2??

Table: students

```
id   mathematics   biology   student 
--   -----------   -------   -------
0    6             8         Peter
1    6             8         Peter
2    3             9         Aaron
3    8             9         Alicia
4    1             4         Peter
5    7             7         Aaron
6    6             5         Rachel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041569/mysql-query-select-then-delete

Comment: After all the deleting is done, what should the table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Uueerdo, who pointed me to this direction, I got it to work.

```
DELETE FROM testtable 
WHERE mathematics =8 
OR student IN (
    SELECT stu
    FROM (
        SELECT student AS stu
        FROM `testtable`
        GROUP BY `student`
        HAVING count( 1 ) >1
    )tmp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (I say might because MySQL may not appreciate referencing the DELETE table in the subquery):

```
DELETE FROM testable 
WHERE mathematics = 8 
OR student IN (
   SELECT student 
   FROM `testtable` 
   GROUP BY `student` 
   HAVING count(1) > 1
)
;
```

This way is longer, but pretty much guaranteed:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t` 
  SELECT student, count(student) AS cnt 
  FROM `testtable` 
  GROUP BY `student` 
  HAVING cnt > 1
;
DELETE FROM testable 
WHERE mathematics = 8 
OR student IN ( SELECT student FROM `t` )
;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `t`;
```

Comment: You were right MySQL didn't like it: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'testtable' for update in FROM clause. I'm testing your second idea now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Your first answer was close. By  wrapping the condition in one more select I got  rid of the error. ty

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE x
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON (y.student = x.student AND y.id <> x.id) 
    OR (y.id = x.id AND y.mathematics = 8);
```